# Reconnecting an external Wi-Fi antenna to a camera PCB. Where and how?

Tags: pcb, antenna, wifi, camera, coaxial

I own a BirdFy Netvue bird feeder. It has a Wi-Fi camera to capture pictures and video clips as the birds come to feed. Unfortunately, the squirrels completely severed the camera antenna. I bought a new 2.4GHz antenna from Amazon, and I'm now trying to connect it to the camera PCB board. The camera board had no antenna connector, instead the coax was directly soldered to the PCB. I could easily identify where the ground shield of the coax was connected, but the center was much harder to identify (several very tiny and dense PCB pads in the area where the center of the coax was connected).

I had no success after an initial attempt. The camera had very poor Wi-Fi signal. When I tested my antenna connections on the PCB board they appeared shorted. After desoldering and cleaning up the PCB, I directly checked the PCB pads for shorts between them. **I'm guessing that the antenna terminals on the PCB board should not short!** I am attaching a screenshot showing the pads on the PCB board. Red ones are shorting with the large pad on the right where the original shield of the coax was connected. The green ones are not shorting. Where do you advise to connect the antenna signal wire?

[image]